# Python Using nested loops to create a pattern

Tags: python, nested-loops

Using python I am attempting to use nested loops to create this pattern:

```
**
*-**
*--***
*---****
*----*****
```

My code so far has many issues and doesn't work as intended here it is so far

```
for a in range(5):
    print("*", end="")
    print()
    for b in range(a):
      print("-", end="")
```

Can you tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This should work I think

```
for i in range(5):
    print("*",end="")
    for a in range(i):
        print(".",end="")
    print("*"*(i+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(10):
    x = "".join(['-' for s in range(i)])
    y = "".join(['*' for s in range(i + 1)])
    z = "*" + x + y
    print(z)
```

Comment: Well, the `for` inside the list comprehension = nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for a in range(5):
    print("*", end="")
    for b in range(a):
        print("-", end="")
    for b in range(a+1):
        print("*", end="")
    print()
```

You just needed an extra loop. Or, you can do it in one line:

```
for a in range(5):
    print('*'+a*'-'+(a+1)*'*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
for i in range(5):
    print('*' + i*'-' + (i + 1)*'*')
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
for i in range(5):
    print("*" + "-"*i + "*"*(i+1))
```

The output is:

```
**
*-**
*--***
*---****
*----*****
```

Answer (score 0):

> ## One line

I put a space in " _" to make it more visible

```
>>> x = [print("*" + " _"*x + "*" + "*"*x) for x in range(5)]
```

**Output**

```
**
* _**
* _ _***
* _ _ _****
* _ _ _ _*****
```

## If you don't like that ...

```
>>> x1 = lambda x: print("*" + " _"*x + "*" + "*"*x)
>>> for i in range(5):
...  x1(i)
...
**
* _**
* _ _***
* _ _ _****
* _ _ _ _*****
>>>
```

Comment: Bad practice. You're unnecessarily creating a list for your purposes, just so you can have an one-liner.